# Custom server environment variables without .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, environment-variables

What other options are available for setting environment variables?

Many cloud platforms such as Heroku/Cloudways/DO etc have a GUI to set up environment variables, typically for php frameworks like symfony or lavavel.

An example would be

`APP_ENV=production`

Although you can set these via an .htaccess file using `SetEnv APP_ENV "production"` we were looking to find what other ways these can be persistently set. e.g don't do things like `export APP_ENV=production` on the cli or `putenv()` in php?

I would ideally like ideas that work well on shared hosting or cPanel servers if possible.

Thanks

Comment: why not include a file with your variables, common approach. and should work every where. relying on the server especially with shared hosts is never going to be reliable

Comment: If you're writing PHP why do you need environment variables?  Things like this usually go in config files of PHP apps.

Comment: @MattS configs are configs, environment variables are specific to the environment. e.g. you wouldnt want to hardcode say a storage path into your config if it could be different depending on the environment

Comment: How about your Apache VirtualHosts configuration? If you have access to it you can set environment vars there.

Comment: @BeetleJuice sure that would be similar to using SetEnv in .htaccess - would require having the mod_env enabled I believe - but wouldn't work on 90% of shared hosting I imagine, especially not cPanel

Comment: And so you create a config for each environment and symlink to it.  This is much more common practice than using environment variables.

Comment: @MattS I think thats going off topic now a little as it's not what we're asking, as wouldn't work for what we're after with plenty of things e.g laravel

Comment: there are very few shared hosts that will let you do what you think you need to. that's why config files are so common. i would rather use config files on my VPS than environment variables.

Comment: @rtfm systems like dotenv provide a simple way to do this - but as I say the idea is to use environment variables as the ecosystem we're in is based off it quite considerably for many integrations like Sentry

Comment: You use laravel as an example yet the documentation states to create a .env file on each server, no mention of server environment variables: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/configuration#environment-configuration

Comment: If you follow it through it also says "Any variable in your .env file can be overridden by external environment variables such as server-level or system-level environment variables." which means they can be server level - Then if you read into dotenv homepage it says "phpdotenv is made for development environments, and generally should not be used in production. In production, the actual environment variables should be set so that there is no overhead of loading the .env file on each request." - which then suggests maybe having server level is the most appropriate way right?